# Recommend reading on physiological basis of music perception.

Tags: physiology

I am looking for a general description of what happens when people listen to music.

Essentially, I'm looking for which areas of the brain are more active, what substances are secreted, what effect they have, and why we get pleasure from hearing music.

Comment: I don't know how much research has been done on the neuroendocrine aspect of music perception, but this is definitely an interesting question.

Comment: http://www.archive.org/details/onsensationsofto00helmrich - 
"On the sensations of tone as a physiological basis for the theory of music" (1895) is first attempt of such research, but too old and incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

This is by far one of my favorite music texts on that subject precisely:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Your_Brain_On_Music

Comment: No problem!  You can click the green "check mark" next to this answer to accept it if it answers your question (it looks like you have not accepted answers to your other questions as well)